# Row Span AutoGrouping and Bug

Tags: html-table, ag-grid-angular

I've created a plnkr to auto-group row-spans the way you would really expect it to work out of the box IMHO.

Anyhow... doing this surfaces an apparent bug... the rowSpan is not consistently applied to the grid.. if you scroll up and down, it sometimes applies, and sometimes does not.

In the screenshot below... you can see 'Aaron Peirsol' is spanning... but if I scroll up and down it might not span on him... **not consistent**.

[image: grid showing inconsistent rendering]

**Here 'Aaron Peirsol' is no longer spanning all 3 rows** -- all I did was scroll up and back down
[image]

**See this Sample**
https://plnkr.co/edit/UxOcCL1SEY4tScn2?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Here I've added columndefs for the grouping

```
 {
  field: 'athlete',
  rowSpan: params => params.data.groupCount,
  cellClassRules: {
    'cell-span': "data.isFirst && data.groupCount>1",
  },
  width: 200,
},
{field:'groupCount', width: 20}, /*  included for debugging */

{field:'isFirst', width: 20}, /*  included for debugging */
```

And here I'm doing the auto-grouping code:

```
onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
this.http
  .get<any[]>('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json')
  .subscribe((data) => {

    let groupKey = 'athlete';

    let sorted = data.sort((a,b) => (a[groupKey] > b[groupKey]) ? 1 :
     ((b[groupKey] > a[groupKey]) ? -1 : 0));

     let filtered = sorted.filter(x => {
      return x[groupKey] < 'Albert' && x[groupKey];
    });

    var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
      return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
        let keyValue = x[key];
        if (rv[keyValue] === undefined)
        {
          rv[keyValue] = 0;
        }
        if (keyValue) {
          rv[keyValue] ++;
        }
        return rv;
      }, {});
    };

    let grouped = groupBy(filtered, groupKey);
    
    let prev = '';
    for (let i=0; i<filtered.length; i++)
    {
      let keyValue = filtered[i][groupKey];
      filtered[i]['groupCount'] = grouped[keyValue];
      if (keyValue == prev)
      {
        filtered[i]['isFirst'] = false;
      }
      else 
      {
        filtered[i]['isFirst'] = true;
      }
      prev = keyValue;
    }
    this.rowData = filtered});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the issue...
rowSpan function must only return a span count for the first row of the span...
every other row it must return 1

I've updated the plunker

```
public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
{
  field: 'athlete',
  rowSpan: params => params.data.groupRowCount == 1 ? params.data.groupCount: 1,  //THIS IS CRUCIAL.. only return count for first row
  cellClassRules: {
    'cell-span': "data.groupRowCount==1 && data.groupCount>1",
  },
  width: 200,
},
```